# How to place odds ratio of Y value at one standard deviation above and below mean of X to a ggplot (or other R plot)

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, regression, logistic-regression

I've data that look like this.

```
Probability <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
Score2 <- c(2,3,4,2,3,4,2,3,4,4,3,2,3,2,3,2,3,2,3,4,2,3,4,2,3,3,4,3,2,3,2,3,2,3)
Data2 <- data.frame(Probability, Score2)

Data
   Probability Score2
1            1      2
2            1      3
3            1      4
4            1      2
5            1      3
6            1      4
7            1      2
8            1      3
9            1      4
10           0      4
11           0      3
12           0      2
13           0      3
14           0      2
15           0      3
16           0      2
17           0      3
18           1      2
19           1      3
20           1      4
21           1      2
22           1      3
23           1      4
24           1      2
25           1      3
26           1      3
27           0      4
28           0      3
29           0      2
30           0      3
31           0      2
32           0      3
33           0      2
34           0      3
```

I need to plot not just a correlation plot, but also add odds ratios comparing the odds of Y at 1 standard deviation above and below the mean of X (with the corresponding p-value).

The following gets me everything but the odds ratio of +/- 1 SD and its p-value.

```
ggplot(Data2, aes(Score2, Probability))+ 
  geom_smooth(method='lm', alpha = .3, color = "black")+
  stat_cor(method = "pearson", label.x.npc = "left", label.y.npc= "top", label.sep = "
")+
  scale_colour_grey(start = .6, end = .2)+
  scale_fill_grey(start = 0.6, end = 1)+
  theme_classic()+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1), limits = c(0, 1))
```

[image: image of correlation plot without odds ratio]

**Question**

How can I add the odds ratio (comparing Probability at 1 SD above and below the mean of X)?

Answer (score 1):

You could estimate the CI using contrast package for the linear probability model also.

```
library(ggpubr)

mean_x = mean(Score2)
sd_x = sd(Score2)
```

#### Linear Probability Model

```
lm_prob <- lm(Probability ~ Score2,data=Data2)

pred_probs = predict(lm_prob,newdata = data.frame(Score2 = c(mean_x - sd_x, mean_x+sd_x)))
or_pred = (pred_probs[2]/(1-pred_probs[2]))/(pred_probs[1]/(1-pred_probs[1]))
```

#### Logistic Regression

```
glm_prob <- glm(Probability ~ Score2,data=Data2,family=binomial())

glm_pred_probs = predict(glm_prob,newdata = data.frame(Score2 = c(mean_x - sd_x, mean_x+sd_x)),type = "response",se.fit = TRUE)
glm_or_pred = (glm_pred_probs$fit[2]/(1-glm_pred_probs$fit[2]))/(glm_pred_probs$fit[1]/(1-glm_pred_probs$fit[1]))
```

The contrasts statements can be updated with mean_x + sd_x and mean_x - sd_x. It doesn't change the result.

```
library(contrast)
glm_contrast <- 
  contrast(glm_prob, 
           list(Score2 = sd_x),
           list(Score2 = -sd_x)
  )
print(glm_contrast, X = TRUE)

or_ci = paste0(round(exp(glm_contrast$Contrast),2), 
               ", 95% CI:",
               round(exp(glm_contrast$Lower),2),
               ", ",
               round(exp(glm_contrast$Upper),2),
               ", p = ",
               round(glm_contrast$Pvalue,3)
               )
```

#### Plot

```
ggplot(Data2, aes(Score2, Probability))+ 
  geom_smooth(method='lm', alpha = .3, color = "black")+
  stat_cor(method = "pearson", label.x.npc = "left", label.y.npc= "top", label.sep = "
")+
  annotate("text", x=3.0, y=0.9, label= paste0("OR = ",or_ci)) +
  scale_colour_grey(start = .6, end = .2)+
  scale_fill_grey(start = 0.6, end = 1)+
  theme_classic()+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1), limits = c(0, 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

[@jvargh7](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7239826/jvargh7) got me most of the way to this solution (minus the standard deviation bracket) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66467083/1701844)

library(ggpubr)

```
### @jVargh7's code ###    
library(ggplot2)  
library(ggpubr)
  
mean_x = mean(Score2)
sd_x = sd(Score2)

lm_prob <- lm(Probability ~ Score2,data=Data2)

pred_probs = predict(lm_prob,newdata = data.frame(Score2 = c(mean_x - sd_x, mean_x+sd_x)))
or_pred = (pred_probs[2]/(1-pred_probs[2]))/(pred_probs[1]/(1-pred_probs[1]))

glm_prob <- glm(Probability ~ Score2,data=Data2,family=binomial())

glm_pred_probs = predict(glm_prob,newdata = data.frame(Score2 = c(mean_x - sd_x, mean_x+sd_x)),type = "response",se.fit = TRUE)
glm_or_pred = (glm_pred_probs$fit[2]/(1-glm_pred_probs$fit[2]))/(glm_pred_probs$fit[1]/(1-glm_pred_probs$fit[1]))

install.packages("contrast")
library(contrast)
glm_contrast <- contrast(glm_prob, list(Score2 = sd_x), list(Score2 = -sd_x))
print(glm_contrast, X = TRUE)

or_ci = paste0(round(exp(glm_contrast$Contrast),2), 
               ", 95% CI: ",
               round(exp(glm_contrast$Lower),2),
               ", ",
               round(exp(glm_contrast$Upper),2),
               ", p = ",
               round(glm_contrast$Pvalue,3)
)   

ggplot(Data2, aes(Score2, Probability))+ 
  geom_smooth(method='lm', alpha = .3, color = "black")+
  stat_cor(method = "pearson", label.x = 2.75, label.y= .6, label.sep = ",")+
  scale_colour_grey(start = .6, end = .2)+
  scale_fill_grey(start = 0.6, end = 1)+
  theme_classic()+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1), limits = c(0, 1))+ 
### new code ###
  geom_bracket(xmin = mean(Score2)-sd(Score2), 
               xmax = mean(Score2)+sd(Score2), 
               y.position = .9, 
               label = paste0("OR = ", or_ci), 
               tip.length = c(0.42, 0.29),
               vjust = -1)
```

Example output below

[image: image of linear regression plot with odds ratio of Y at 1 S.D. above and below the mean of X]

Again, thanks to [@jvargh7](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7239826/jvargh7) for getting me most of the way to this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66467083/1701844).

Comment: Updated the solution for contrast estimation.